# Android NotificationManager giving me "no valid small icon" error

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, notificationmanager

I am having a strange error with notification manager.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data)
{
     Log.i(TAG, "IP : " + (String) data.get("ip"));
     NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
     Intent acceptNextIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.BROADCAST_KEY_ACCEPT);
//        acceptNextIntent.putExtra("ip", (String) data.get("blah")); //add stuff here
     PendingIntent acceptNextPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, acceptNextIntent, 0);

     Intent declineNextIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.BROADCAST_KEY_DECLINE);
     PendingIntent declineNextPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, declineNextIntent, 0);

     NotificationCompat.Action acceptAction = new NotificationCompat.Action
                .Builder(R.drawable.common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_light, "Grant Request", acceptNextPendingIntent).build();

     NotificationCompat.Action declineAction = new NotificationCompat.Action
                .Builder(R.drawable.common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark, "Decline Request", declineNextPendingIntent).build();

     NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("New Password Request From " + (String) data.get("ip"))
                .addAction(acceptAction)
                .addAction(declineAction);

     notificationManager.notify(1, notification.build()); //ERROR HERE
```

Error Message:

```
9.474 9327-9371/com.inh.amnesia_application I/MyGcmListenerService: IP : 128.239.213.39
11-10 19:49:59.477 9327-9371/com.inh.amnesia_application E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
11-10 19:49:59.477 9327-9371/com.inh.amnesia_application E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.inh.amnesia_application, PID: 9327
11-10 19:49:59.477 9327-9371/com.inh.amnesia_application E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid notification (no valid small icon): Notification(pri=0 contentView=com.inh.amnesia_application/0x1090085 vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x0 color=0x00000000 actions=2 vis=PRIVATE)
11-10 19:49:59.477 9327-9371/com.inh.amnesia_application E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:222)
11-10 19:49:59.477 9327-9371/com.inh.amnesia_application E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:194)
11-10 19:49:59.477 9327-9371/com.inh.amnesia_application E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.inh.amnesia_application.MyGcmListenerService.onMessageReceived(MyGcmListenerService.java:65)
11-10 19:49:59.477 9327-9371/com.inh.amnesia_application E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzt(Unknown Source)
11-10 19:49:59.477 9327-9371/com.inh.amnesia_application E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzk(Unknown Source)
11-10 19:49:59.477 9327-9371/com.inh.amnesia_application E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zza(Unknown Source)
11-10 19:49:59.477 9327-9371/com.inh.amnesia_application E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService$1.run(Unknown Source)
11-10 19:49:59.477 9327-9371/com.inh.amnesia_application E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
11-10 19:49:59.477 9327-9371/com.inh.amnesia_application E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
11-10 19:49:59.477 9327-9371/com.inh.amnesia_application E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Does this mean that the icons I am trying to access does not exist? I am not sure how to interpret this error and searching this error message does not yield anything.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You're actually not setting an icon for the push notification. Add `.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.your_icon)` to your notification.

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("New Password Request From " + (String) data.get("ip"))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.your_icon)
            .addAction(acceptAction)
            .addAction(declineAction);
```

Comment: I have found the source [code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/app/NotificationManager.java#306) , it seems only target api > lolipop will have the error.

Comment: I'm getting this error using Notification to set the LEDs, in which case the icon should be irrelevant as it's not displayed...

Answer (score 10):

You have not called [`setSmallIcon()` on the `NotificationCompat.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setSmallIcon%28int%29). This provides the icon that will go in the status bar while the `Notification` is active.

Comment: Hi,@CommonsWare, I added a notification on a `Service` and called `setSmallIcon()`. But still getting same error `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid notification (no valid small icon)`

Comment: @AGMTazim: I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve], including the code where you create the `Notification` and the resulting stack trace. Perhaps there is an issue with the drawable resource that you are using with `setSmallIcon()`.

Answer (score 7):

According to the Android NotificationManager [Source Code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/app/NotificationManager.java#306)

```
if (mContext.getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
    if (notification.getSmallIcon() == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid notification (no valid small icon): "
                + notification);
    }
}
```

This error only happened when you set target API > LOLLIPOP_MR1(22) and notification do not have a small icon.

Answer (score 1):

This suddenly started happening to my application.  After some research, I found this change in my manifest file actually started causing it.

from:

```
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" />
```

to:

```
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
```

I saw somewhere that somebody noted that it only checks for the icon if the target sdk version is set.  Sure enough, in the source, there is this :

```
if (mContext.getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
    if (notification.getSmallIcon() == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid notification (no valid small icon): "
                + notification);
    }
}
```

Luckily, the solution was simple, just define the icon in the manifest:

```
  <application android:label="MyApp" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" >
```