# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid notification (no valid small icon)

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, exception

Hello Can someone advise me how to make a notification without receiving this exception:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid notification (no valid small icon): Notification(channel=null pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x0 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE)

The code:

public void notifyThis(String text) {

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        //When sdk version is larger than26
        String id = "channel_1";
        String description = "143";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(id, description, importance);
        channel.enableLights(true);
        channel.enableVibration(true);//
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(MapsActivity.this, id)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.screenmec))
                .setContentTitle("MECTS.SA")
                .setContentText(text)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();
        manager.notify(1, notification); }
    else {
        //When sdk version is less than26
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MapsActivity.this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.screenmec))
                .setContentTitle("MECTS.SA")
                .setContentText(text)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .build();
        manager.notify(1,notification); }
    NotificationManager mannager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mannager.notify(0,builder.build());
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android NotificationManager giving me no valid small icon error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33642484/android-notificationmanager-giving-me-no-valid-small-icon-error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're building two notifications. The other is based on an empty builder that does not have small icon or any other content:

> ```
> NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
> ```

...

> ```
> NotificationManager mannager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
> mannager.notify(0,builder.build());
> ```

You can remove this code.

Comment: It worked perfectly, Thank you! I have been suffering to solve this.