# Flutter jitsi meet not working on android after release

Tags: flutter, push-notification, jitsi, jitsi-meet

it was working in release apk but after deployment steps its no longer working it crash whenever i try to join a meeting
with error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid notification (no valid small icon): Notification(channel=JitsiOngoingConferenceChannel shortcut=null contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0xa color=0x00000000 category=call actions=2 vis=PUBLIC)
```

my proguards rules is fine it was working before

Comment: I think You should add  small icon for notification.

Comment: can you tell me how to add it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61932010/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-invalid-notification-no-valid-small-icon

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33642484/android-notificationmanager-giving-me-no-valid-small-icon-error

Comment: https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/issues/11847

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved after adding ic_notification icon